# Autofac and WebForms - passing non-constant parameters, resolved parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, webforms, autofac

I'm just getting started with Autofac and I have the following code:

```
public class _default : System.Web.UI.Page, IUserInformationProvider
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        ControllerFactory cf;
        using (scope == ((Global_asax)this.Context.ApplicationInstance).ContainerProvider.ApplicationContainer.BeginLifetimeScope()) {
            cf = scope.Resolve<IControllerFactory>();  // <-- would love to pass "this" somewhere here, but how???
        }
    }

}
```

ControllerFactory is defined below and also takes an IUserInformationProvider interface.  I would like to pass the instance of the WebForm as a parameter to Resolve IControllerFactory.

```
public class ControllerFactory : IControllerFactory
{
    protected IUserInformationProvider _userInformation;
    public ControllerFactory(IUserInformationProvider userInformation)
    {
        _userInformation = userInformation;
    }
}
```

Looking through the documentation, I see that there are 3 parameter types (Named, Typed, Resolved), but the first 2 take only constant values.  It seems like Resolved parameters are the way to go, but I'm kind of lost as to how to implement it, or if that's even the right strategy.  And what would the builder.Register look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass additional parameter not just when registering but when resolving a type.

The `ResolvedParameter` can only be used if your `IUserInformationProvider` was already registered in the container so it probably won't work in your case.

However you can use `NamedParameter` where you need to pass the parameter name what you have used in the contrustor so `"userInformation"` and the value `this`:

```
cf = scope.Resolve<IControllerFactory>(
    new NamedParameter("userInformation", this));
```

Or you can use the `TypedParameter` where you need to pass the type of the parameter in this case `typeof(IUserInformationProvider)` and again the value of `this`:

```
cf = scope.Resolve<IControllerFactory>(
    new TypedParameter(typeof(IUserInformationProvider), this));
```

If you are looking for some general guide about how you can integrate WebForms with Autofac you can start with the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/WebFormsIntegration)

Answer (score 0):

Break the dependency cycle by introducing a property dependency in your controller:

```
public class ControllerFactory : IControllerFactory
{
    public ControllerFactory() { }

    // Property dependency (part of IControllerFactory interface)
    public IUserInformationProvider UserInformation { get; set; }
}
```

This way you can set the value after Autofac constructed that type:

```
var factory = scope.Resolve<IControllerFactory>();
factory.UserInformation = this;
cf = factory;
```

Comment: Yeah, but with that you turned the `UserInformation` into an optional dependency, and now in theory in every method of the `ControllerFactory` where you would use the `UserInformation` you need to check that the property is not `null`...